# How to build a URL with checkbox and radio values?

Tags: jquery, forms, url, serialization

I bluntly copy pasted this basic [serialize() example](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to a local html, and it works to print the string (obviously).

But I'm having a hard time to create a url with this this string. My goal is to create a link (or form action) that looks like this:

```
<a href="node/1?single=Single&multiple=Multiple&multiple=Multiple3&check=check2&radio=radio1">Click me</a>
```

But when a do the following:

```
var mylink = showValues();
document.write('<a href="node/1?'+mylink+'">Click me</a>');
```

... it throws an "undefined" error at me.

Anyone knows how to get this done please?

This is the full code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>serialize demo</title>  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form class="myform">
  <select name="single">
    <option>Single</option>
    <option>Single2</option>
  </select>

  <br>
  <select name="multiple" multiple="multiple">
    <option selected="selected">Multiple</option>
    <option>Multiple2</option>
    <option selected="selected">Multiple3</option>
  </select>

  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check1" id="ch1">
  <label for="ch1">check1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check2" checked="checked" id="ch2">
  <label for="ch2">check2</label>

  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio1" checked="checked" id="r1">
  <label for="r1">radio1</label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio2" id="r2">
  <label for="r2">radio2</label>
</form>

<p><tt id="results"></tt></p>

<script>
  function showValues() {
    var str = $( ".myform" ).serialize();
    $( "#results" ).text( str );
  }
  $( "input[type='checkbox'], input[type='radio']" ).on( "click", showValues );
  $( "select" ).on( "change", showValues );
  showValues();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what does `showValues` return?

Comment: Your call to `document.write` looks fine. It's likely something in your `showValues` function. Would you mind sharing that? Have you tried using Chrome's debugger to see where the error is?

Comment: Hi, I've added the full code in the OP. `showValues` returns this string: `single=Single&multiple=Multiple&multiple=Multiple3&check=check2&radio=radio1` (depending on what's selected in the form).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks user3191461, now it does show the string on page load, but it doesn't change when other options are being selected.

I figured out this approach works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function showValues() {
    var str = $( ".myform" ).serialize();
    $("a.mylink").attr("href", "node/1?"+str);   
  }
  $( "input[type='checkbox'], input[type='radio']" ).on( "click", showValues );
  $( "select" ).on( "change", showValues );  

   showValues();

</script>
```

As you can see, I added `$("a.mylink").attr("href", "node/1?"+str);` to the script, and put the following html-code outside the script tags:

```
<a href="node/1" class="mylink">Click me</a>
```

(Note that Drupal may require the `jQuery.noConflict();` method)

**EDIT:** still a problem. The checkboxes should be built like this `check=1,2` (as an array) instead of `check=1&check=2`...

**Solution (checkboxes as array):**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery.noConflict();

  function showValues() {
    var radios = jQuery('input[type=\'radio\']:checked').map(function() { return this.value; }).get().join(', ');
    var checkboxes = jQuery('input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked').map(function() { return this.value; }).get().join(', ');
    jQuery("a.mylink").attr("href", "node/1?chks="+checkboxes+"&rads="+radios);  
  }
  jQuery( "input[type='checkbox']" ).on( "click", showValues );
  jQuery( "input[type='radio']" ).on( "click", showValues );

   showValues();

</script>
```

The link will be node/1 by default, but once an option is clicked, the string gets built behind it. In this case I'll be starting with empty values, so no need to do more.

But in case I'd be starting with selected values (which will have to be placed in the url by default), my solution is not going to suffice.

So the perfect solution would be a combination (or an approach) that both combines [user3191461's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30508055/how-to-output-a-serialized-string-in-a-url#answer-30508775) with mine. Any idea how that could be done please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function showValues() {
    var str = $( "form" ).serialize();
    $( "#results" ).text( str );
    return str; // need to return result
}
```

Your function does something, but doesn't actually return it.  In order to fill myLink, you need to return "str"